# How to run test on Safari driver on Mac with intern

Tags: javascript, intern

Im using intern.js i like to run my tests script on safari webdriver
Actualy a run my test on chrome driver and it work fine

```js
    capabilities: {
                'chrome.chromedriverVersion': '2.24'
    },

    environments: [
 
        {
            browserName: 'safari',
            version: '10.0.1',
            platform: 'MAC',
            'safari.options': {
                dataDir: '/Users/frahem/Library/Safari'

            }
                }
 
        ],

    maxConcurrency: 2,

    tunnel: 'NullTunnel',
```

Answer (score 0):

To run your tests with Intern and safari webdriver, you need first manually install safari webdriver as Safari browser extension (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver). The driver inverts the traditional client/server relationship and communicates with the Selenium WebDriver client using WebSockets.

Then run selenium webdriver from command line: java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -port 4444.

Setting of browserName: 'safari' in intern is enough, start intern-runner.

Hope, it will help.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. What the error you are getting?